# What are the things I have to be aware of when changing a file servers file protocol from AFP to SMB?

Tags: linux, macos, samba, smb, afp

In a Mac dominated network, I want to change the servers (Samba 4.1.20) file service from AFP only to SMB only due to AFP being more and more deprecated in [macOS Sierra](http://www.apple.com/macos/sierra/).

The main problem are the mangled names, because via AFP were a lot of files and folders names with illegal characters (from SMB point of view).

1. Is the option `mangle names = no` in the `smb.conf` a safe way to solve the issue named above? Safe means without the risk of data loss or corrupting anything.
2. Is there a safe way to rename all non-conform files and folders so that they conform to the smb format? (e.g. replacing all `.` at the end of a folder or all `:` in file names with an underscore `_`)
3. What do you superusers suggest is the best way to perform that major change? Anything else to be aware of?

---

#### Additional Info:

When I set the option `mangle names = no` the folders are displayed normally when connecting via SMB on a Mac.
But the folder is displayed without any content. And that is where I got afraid of having data loss.
(contents are still there, I switched back to AFP)